# wordpress menu dropdown item not showing after first dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I just configured a wordpress theme with woocommerce and I have updated product categories and added them to a menu. Now my problem is after first sub menu item next sub items are not loading. Please check the screenshot of both frontend and backend menu structure.

Wp backend:
[image: wp backend]

Wp frontend:
[image: wp frontend]

Answer (score 0):

You can see your menu and you can modified this.

You can Appearance/Menus and create a new menu. Select items from `Pages` and put your `new menu` how you want it. (You just do drag-drop)

[image]

Comment: you have not understood my issue . check my both screenshot .

Comment: Do you want see your submenus in main page? You can create a new menu and add this menu to main page.

Comment: You add **categories** but no add to **menu**.

Comment: my menu is only for categories . it is  vertical menu . please check my site " https://azahar.in/market/ "

Comment: please check the pdf file " https://www.dropbox.com/s/tb4siys2sdtfxia/Menus%20%E2%80%B9%20My%20Blog%20%E2%80%94%20WordPress.pdf?dl=0  "

Comment: I think your theme doesn't support third-submenu. You can search a modul for this or u can do in your theme's code. Like this `<ul><li>submenu</li><li>submenu2</li></ul>`

Comment: can i have the url of that module please ? or in which file i  have to put the code ?

Comment: I haven't a wp now. I can't look but you can search like 'mega menu'.
I didn't try but you can look this modules: https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/    http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/